# Redis: ioredis vs. lua script

Tags: node.js, redis, lua, ioredis

my question is - is it better to call redis from a JS library or using a Lua script?
Redis supports Lua as a scripting language, but is it more efficient than using something like ioredis in Node.js? How exactly are these scripts executed?

For example we have the function call in Lua:

```
redis.call('ZADD', key, ...) 
redis.call('ZREM', key, ...)
```

and the corresponding code in ioredis:

```
redis.zadd(key, ...)
redis.zrem(key, ...)
```

If we were to do those calls in a while loop in Lua or Node, how would they perform?
Are the Lua scripts executed somehow internally in Redis or do they require connections everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using ioredis in production (which has huge traffic) for couple of years and it is working very well. Did not try Lua though. You can surely go for ioredis.